# How do I get an ID from the Objectstore when i left-click on the tree-row (tree-node) in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, tree, dojo

I stored some data like this in a store:

```
{id:"r1",name:"Rule1",data1:"InTo1",data2:"RuJa1",data3:"IO1",data4:"TS1", parent:"r0"},
{id:"r2",name:"Rule2",data1:"InTo2",data2:"RuJa2",data3:"IO2",data4:"TS2", parent:"r0"},
```

I built a tree with it and now I try do get the id ("r1") when I "left-click" on the tree node ("Rule1").

Is it possible to get the Id with a simple "left-click" on the tree-node (not with a menu)?

**my tree:**

```
var tree = new Tree({
    model: myModel,
    showRoot: true, 
    openOnClick: false,
    id:"tree"
});
```

**my "left-click-function":**

```
dojo.connect(tree, "onClick", function(item){

// Here I want to get the ID

});
```

[This is my tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b00yr.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem Solved!!**

With the simple code:

```
var getObj = dijit.byId("tree").get("selectedItem");
```

you will get the object in the store.
Now you can display all youre properties easily.

For example:

```
 console.log(getObj.id)
```

console: `"r1"` (when you click on Rule1).

The properties will change when you click on another tree-node (Rule2,Rule3..)

**Function:**

```
dojo.connect(tree, "onClick", function(item){
var getObj =dijit.byId("tree").get("selectedItem");
console.log(getObj);
```

Thank you!